# How to get nested scope object to compile and be extended in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEV1DYFAEwGU0IxgAeAGTxAOIGc4yLgA+ACgCg44ANpgDWwAFxwaAGj5wiAQxjyJbSgBV5AIwHA1AT0oBtGgF0Z-MPKiEYAfgmphKCAHcUMgJQry6g9RoccADestYwSFC4QXKK8lKCIsDxltYo8AC+PJk8oJCweChIALasPsDBsgDCVkRwALxwAERoNY3mcABywEzwDY0o3TBtWTw54NDwMH6l7F09ACKx+pT1FfwDPRIh-PxCohL9g40A3LL8CBAQczASPVCYKADmp-zpp2+juRNwUyuqwNUoERFkpluUGts4C0gVsznAABbAAQCCC3GD3J4vHYuaACIgSACCUCg8j0VEKRU0wCgHCxHw+Yzyk2m-w02l00whsg2NxmlGuIPkYKx0PxfIBNUFwqyp0Z31+5VZfiosgJ9EYRBY-zgAB84KgiMAEA9gLU9Y5nG5VgajSaiO0AELqwia8Vgqhq83EW0DM36lBOVwoQJewNWr2G42+63eqOmniBBpq-AurVlWS2OBOlPMN1+OGZyE7HYKJTedhsnRgwwEkxY4u7RKE+sNlI2exZluvOGwhsl2Ll9RaKt+Gt1uHFvbiOAErs7NtpDsWoNzzL8XsN0vKOAQTQAK2AGDnU4cActKDnC7sp7DF7hHyAA) TypeScript code:

```
export function extendScope<L extends Scope>(
  like: L,
  data: ScopeTableType[L],
  parent?: unknown,
): ScopeType<L> {
  return { data, like, parent }
}

export enum Scope {
  Card = "card",
  Nest = "nest",
}

export type ScopeNestDataType = {
  nest: {
    like: "nest-data";
    fooNest: string;
  };
};

export type ScopeCardDataType = {
  card: {
    hello: string;
    world: Array<number>;
  };
};

export type ScopeTableType = {
  nest: ScopeNestDataType;
  card: ScopeCardDataType;
};

export type ScopeType<
  A extends Scope | undefined | unknown = undefined,
  B extends ScopeType<A | undefined | unknown> | unknown | undefined = undefined
> = A extends Scope
  ? B extends ScopeType
    ? {
        data: ScopeTableType[A];
        like: A;
        parent?: B;
      }
    : {
        data: ScopeTableType[A];
        like: A;
        parent?: unknown;
      }
  : {
      data: object;
      like: unknown;
      parent?: unknown;
    };
```

The `extendScope` function is erroring in TypeScript though:

> Type '{ data: ScopeNestDataType | { base?: { text_mesh?: ReadonlySet<string | [string, string]> | undefined; link_mesh?: ReadonlySet<string | string[] | [string, string[]]> | undefined; ... 13 more ...; sort?: {} | undefined; } | undefined; ... 6 more ...; like?: Scope.DeckCard | undefined; }; like: Scope; parent: unknown...' is not assignable to type 'ScopeType<L, undefined>'.ts(2322)

[image]

I have tried every combination of ways of trying to get this to work but nothing seems to work. How do I get it to work?

Basically I just want to be able to do this:

```
const parentScope: ScopeType<Scope.Card> = {
  like: Scope.Card,
  data: {
    card: {
      hello: 'abcdefg',
      world: [1, 2, 3]
    }
  }
}

const childScope = extendScope(Scope.Nest, parentScope, {
  nest: {
    like: 'nest-data',
    fooNest: 'asdf',
  },
});

console.log(childScope);
// {
//   like: 'nest',
//   data: {
//     nest: {
//       like: 'nest-data',
//       fooNest: 'asdf',
//     },
//   },
//   parent: {
//     like: 'card',
//     data: {
//       card: {
//         hello: 'abcdefg',
//         world: [1, 2, 3]
//       }
//     }
//   }
// }
```

Perhaps I have to pass some generics in there, I dunno:

```
const childScope = extendScope<Scope.Nest>(Scope.Nest, parentScope, {
  nest: {
    like: 'nest-data',
    fooNest: 'asdf',
  },
});
```

Any ideas how to get this to work?

Note, I tried to make it so the generics were optional, hence all the `unknown` and `undefined` stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working!

```
export type ParentScopeType<S> = S extends ScopeType<
  unknown,
  infer PS
>
  ? PS | ParentScopeType<PS>
  : never
  
export type ScopeType<
  S extends Scope | unknown = unknown,
  P extends unknown | undefined = unknown
> = {
  data: S extends Scope ? ScopeTableType[S] : unknown;
  like: S;
  parent?: P extends ScopeType<infer T extends Scope, infer Q>
    ? ScopeType<T, Q>
    : never;
};

export type ScopeValueType<
  L extends Scope | unknown,
  T extends ScopeType<L>,
  K extends ScopeKeyListType<L, T>
> = T["data"] extends { [key in K]: unknown }
  ? T["data"][K]
  : T["parent"] extends infer O
  ? O extends ScopeType<infer X>
    ? ScopeValueType<X, O, ScopeKeyListType<X, O>>
    : never
  : never;


export function extendScope<
  S extends Scope,
  P extends unknown | undefined = unknown
>(
  like: S,
  data: S extends Scope ? ScopeTableType[S] : unknown,
  parent?: P extends ScopeType<infer T extends Scope, infer Q>
    ? ScopeType<T, Q>
    : never
): ScopeType<S, P> {
  return { data, like, parent };
}

export function getPropertyValueFromScope<
  L extends Scope,
  S extends ScopeType<L>,
  K extends ScopeKeyListType<L, S>
>(scope: S, path: K): ScopeValueType<L, S, K> | undefined {
  let source: ScopeSetType<S> | undefined = scope;

  while (source) {
    if (path in source.data) {
      break;
    } else {
      source = source.parent;
    }
  }

  if (!source) {
    return;
  }

  return source.data[path];
}

export function setPropertyValueOnScope<
  L extends Scope,
  S extends ScopeType<L>,
  K extends ScopeKeyListType<L, S>
>(scope: S, property: K, value: ScopeValueType<L, S, K>): void {
  if (property in scope.data) {
    scope.data[property] = value;
  } else if (scope.parent) {
    setPropertyValueOnScope(scope.parent, property, value);
  } else {
    throw new Error(`Property not defined on scope`);
  }
}
```