# How to dynamically set property on scope chain in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have a nested tree of scopes like this:

```
const parentScope = {
  data: {
    foo: 'bar'
  }
}
const child1Scope = {
  parent: parentScope,
  data: {
    hello: 'world',
    one: 2
  }
}
const child2Scope = {
  parent: child1Scope,
  data: {
    a: true
  }
}
```

I would like to use them like this:

```
setProperty(child2Scope, 'a', false)
setProperty(child2Scope, 'hello', 'there')
setProperty(child2Scope, 'foo', 'baz')

function setProperty(scope, property, value) {
  if (property in scope.data) {
    scope.data[property] = value
  } else if (scope.parent) {
    setProperty(scope.parent, property, value)
  } else {
    throw new Error(`Property not defined on scope`)
  }
}
```

How can I properly do this in TypeScript? Each scope will have a defined `type` structured, if that helps.

The definition for my scope object is roughly like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74871018/how-to-get-nested-scope-object-to-compile-and-be-extended-in-typescript), though I'm still working on getting it working.

Particularly relevant is that the `parent` in the scope type definition can be `unknown`, as seen in my most current attempt:

```
export type ScopeType<
  A extends Scope,
  B extends ScopeType<Scope> | unknown = unknown,
> = {
  data: ScopeTableType[A]
  like: A
  parent?: B
}
```

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZwKZQAoCc4AdVZQCeAFMhHqgFyIDKF+AKkfgDz2UB8ANIrjvkJEaAa1RE4wOg1TM2HfD0QA3AIYAbENUTgRYOAHcwASkQBvAFCJEMKSX6UhNpOUoA6ACaqoq05evWrvie3qoA2g6CxAC6iAC8KhpaVogAvoio6mg2dkGobriqWKhgUH4pgejYjsRkMgVFJVC8kQTEvGqaqMYp6ZnZ-gFQABY4BohgqOMAolg4WCQABtVRRBNwUIgeqMAwkx6ICCgyiz3WqRYXFqgAHrhwhIjE+NKUcqisKQCCGTdQJR5kK98NwUgAhX7-MCA4GyFgfBSoTiIAA+OjAekMSASun0RlByISgy8PhoiMYqgARuo4fgwl9oil1DAxDQvilCsVSgB+Ghgy4Wa53B6bEogAC2sPMKQAwkUDgkAEQQeWK0HWAByqGQmyVkx1aoFQvuj2eqFhWp1ABFQu94tLrPqoDRBtZmazEIqnYqANwVRDAOBwS3OlBQLB7ADmfvOftSfuNIqe8NhcqwHhtPjtRJSKvTLv9w0y6jgNB1EbA0f9Bge6g8bLmqiIrDAEspBE4MbScYTtxNmzNsIp1Np5pzju1ocRIczqneXbz9dT8tn88ufqAA) is my attempt trying to type it:

```
function setProperty(scope: ScopeType<Scope>, property: keyof ScopeType<Scope>, value: unknown) {
  if (property in scope.data) {
    scope.data[property] = value
  } else if (scope.parent) {
    setProperty(scope.parent, property, value)
  } else {
    throw new Error(`Property not defined on scope`)
  }
}
```

Comment: Is a scope just an object with arbitrary "data" and an optional "parent" that is a scope? Or is there something Im missing?

Comment: Yeah that's it. It has arbitrary data, but the `data` will ultimately be typed as I need to do `scope.data.foo` and such in certain other places in the code, so it is not completely arbitrary.

Comment: Also, if `unknown` is option for the parent scope type here, then how would you expect any of this to work? Like if any scope is `unknown` than the function would have to accept `property: string, value: unknown`, since those would be unknowable to the type system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to traverse a tree, and then bail when you are out of parents. That means this will take some recursive conditional types to pull off.

So given the data:

```
const parentScope = {
  data: { foo: 'bar' }
}
const child1Scope = {
  parent: parentScope,
  data: { hello: 'world', one: 2 }
}
const child2Scope = {
  parent: child1Scope,
  data: { a: true }
}
```

We can derive a type to describe that like so:

```
type Scope = {
  parent?: Scope
  data: Record<string, unknown>
}
```

---

Now to make this work:

```
setProperty(child2Scope, 'foo', 'baz')
```

We need a generic type that constrains that second `property` argument, and another type for the `value`.

Here's one for the keys:

```
// Get all possible keys in scope
type ScopeKeys<T extends Scope> =
  
  // does this scope have a parent?
  T['parent'] extends Scope 

    // Get a union of the keys at this level and recursivelly
    // get the keys of the parent scope
    ? keyof T['data'] | ScopeKeys<T['parent']> 

    // No parent, just return the keys of this level.
    : keyof T['data']


// test
type K = ScopeKeys<typeof child2Scope>
// type K = "foo" | "hello" | "one" | "a"
```

This recursive conditional type collects all scopes `data` keys as a union. It keeps recursing up `parent` until there is no parent.

---

Now we need the one for the value:

```
// Get the value type of a specific key in a scope.
type ScopeValue<T extends Scope, K extends string> =
  
  // Does the data have this key?
  T['data'] extends { [key in K]: unknown }

    // Get the value type of this key
    ? T['data'][K]

    // No key found, so is there a parent scope?
    : T['parent'] extends Scope

      // Ask the parent scope the same question
      ? ScopeValue<T['parent'], K>

      // No parent scope, and we failed to find a match, so return never
      : never

// tests
type V = ScopeValue<typeof child2Scope, 'one'>
// type V = number
```

This type does something similar to the previous one, alrhough instead of collection results from each level, it's looking for just one. The general flow is:

1. Does this level have the key?
2. If yes, return its value
3. If not, does this level have a parent?
4. If yes, go to step 1.
5. If not, return `never`

Now typing the function is pretty simple:

```
function setProperty<
  T extends Scope,
  K extends ScopeKeys<T>
>(
  scope: T,
  property: K,
  value: ScopeValue<T, K>
) {
  if (property in scope.data) {
    scope.data[property] = value
  } else if (scope.parent) {
    setProperty(scope.parent, property, value)
  } else {
    throw new Error(`Property not defined on scope`)
  }
}
```

Which you'd use like so:

```
setProperty(child2Scope, 'a', false) // fine on 1st level
setProperty(child2Scope, 'a', 123) // error, wrong value type
setProperty(child2Scope, 'b', {} as any) // error, no prop by that name in scope

setProperty(child2Scope, 'hello', 'there') // 2nd level, fine
setProperty(child2Scope, 'hello', 123) // error, wrong value type

setProperty(child2Scope, 'foo', 'baz') // 3nd level, fine
setProperty(child2Scope, 'foo', false) // error, wrong value type
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAygxge0lAvFA3gKClMBDAJwgDtgB+ALlkUmygBM9g8qAlCRA+gHgGdgCAS2IBzADRQArsQDWxBAHdiAPkwBfTJgD0WqAHEIwKHgA2J3Al69BAIxPQZEELyjCovGhEyhk8JBABpJ15uABUoCAAPYBJ6Fz9IZVQ6Oh0GBAgXYAALQRcPfyhsvAA3aDxcQhJyOlCAbQByfCJSBoBdCOjY+M8oTRwcNIMjCulBBGIoBAAzKByHYOMjHLyoezLzPGJ6KCI4SQJrDZMQOkHdEUM57IXnKdn5ypajAtoBqDIoRxAZqHqGxjMdpQAA+1H8QWcYUazWq7SS-QGaQAcggntUJAArST8XaGA6TR7fFy-FYudYQEwAOjOUCo31+-0BeGBmiGV0eJVMkmgPmgvwqvEgcEE00EcC+Tlck0FnhpfPBkAAatyIGFOjFtj1-BIAhruu4BMIREkUClzlAACIZLI3BhMCrFMrXVbfMi1RrM4FRTVxDBQOrfaVQAJtKjSOSKSYaWns5Z2rkmHlzcD8h65FzfWmfJkO9p1UOIi2oyUgKDTBDSegSXho1bzIjGdGkdyed3vKj-WGtDo+g0JLy0i0AQV4Mmu0G7L16j14eAAttAAI48-jjYhDj6KiAqpNqrtVHu61SblFoqetnXGbZQBTQaZ4QT2HbANFim8VedMODZGtoojAASUDEBAZQEJuVAgWBmjaLoMT8LwmgKnqaADpCIR8r8P5PvQABMA5JGkABEFYIERoJQERNxmGRFFERMEDkWCRF4ER3iplASqoNuu48twmGzNhJh4QOEgNAxDSEXBHFcWgxCSPONgQOB7G+J4w7ceg9rMFQWl4AAYggCCQQpSkEFAagWap0ADgAQpp2ksP6NiGcZhpCKIFkSFOVADhpMYKqEmTAOh3FocE3B2VJUANAZRkNBRDQufF1l-MFvHQKhngZZFni2WJcUIJJUBpPJinKTB0zSHAwDru4hgAAoEP4BCgNwtT6lq25iHQep9l14VQqEqjKAAFHQrwQJ2PU4GAzWQK1IBUAEM1QImPK+dlqphMemAAJQYHQopQKNc0taAwaTVSzIHVg7xXcydRnQtoAdGg61eDglmUrw0DHaNV1TrdtK-cATXnSAANylO3nzcpoASB9e10N9Ji-Yd7w5M1CjARAOMAKIEM1BCjQABuDL1lvIRj0BA74QDsEyXpApPI196gwYgxC4lOA6aXQzK6eWRlUElhAJRoGhc7iQn0AAjHzaB3c2wBULznirYL-rUSYbkNAoCAEMJDQSAxVC4VZUsTDLuTCfhvRK3QPlQLLCsawLDpC05AjJpLMGgxT8OQ7L9tXrFJvlqYv0HWk9NTJMcu4hSJiYAHcOLaNIeiTFLISHLuEAMwx7oynExICjNZ5H0prQacQ5ntsiRrMU2BH6CWXgLhbCAxcREThsSPIuDzVANhljkTDAQuf2TJNmh15TDc4aHkBiTrRViQ2EANL3uE3snEj06njXp6AS929nDTrxH+dFyVJf9wQ5eVyIa2qjXg4L0H59N2HpER2LAAXjve+UAC771ApSQ+wgvBfwzlnZuDR-6HyjhAXupcB63hfm-PcH8YKaCAA)

Comment: This is great! Now how can you remove the need for the `type V = ScopeValue<typeof child2Scope, 'one'>` getting the type from the instances? Can it be more generic and only based on type definitions, not instances somehow? Not sure where to plug that in.

Comment: Sure, you can just use a type there instead of a `typeof value`. `type TestValue = ScopeValue<ScopeB, 'propNameOfParent'>`  See the end of https://tsplay.dev/wXzyOm. Unless I misunderstand you?

Comment: How come you did `& string` like `keyof T['data'] & string`, is it to allow data to be a string?

Comment: Hmm it actually looks like that is not necessary now, but property keys can actually be of type `string | number | symbol`, so that trick can help narrow the property names down to just `string` if you get errors like `"string | number | symbol" is not assignable to "string"`.

Comment: Looks like I still needed it, I got that error you were saying. Here is a follow-up question to where I'm at now, still not quite working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74880109/how-to-resolve-type-k-cannot-be-used-to-index-type-x-in-typescript