# How to resolve Type 'K' cannot be used to index type 'ScopeTableType[L]' in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwMoGMJmHAbwCg44AxadAXjgCIAzS2gGhLgDlgBneG2xbjBZEAvkSKhIsODACeeTDjwBpYLIAyASx4AVecAA8bdQhAwkAEy6LcwVqR2nziKzbx68B9QD5W3uDQ6ANoA5GAAhlBIMCEAuk6W1ti2HoaaiPTAUHAAggkuSUrA3mwA-HAA1moQ9HDBIRbhMOFxcAA+bsCqGtowqQY5zHWhEVGIMbElpABcldW19Y3NceKS0PByCsl4nDwAIk3hqQGEbOkWoLMoqABGWQDcbAI8s8SkpIwQszxQ6QDmj3ecBukVmNwgEAANsBwohAXARI9EatwOsZPpOhQoKgDs1jjQ3nAABbASGQr5wH7-eEAd2gkIsVzQdygSMeElR0k2+G2wB04Ru0Pxpw+lFmvKxOMOqXhzxg4qKuxguKO+jZKKkGwxvP6bDyoGcrl59jgACF8q5kIgKogIDTECcrTa7YgiP4CWwluEFSkBUL9EEcrF4ZDNFVZjl4aNoqVZuaDYlOv10plso4EwVOkMU1k4ABFKbvcqmtgzOACABuWVE7LWXO1RQAauFIcg+fojKQTBmjUUTemzImdR2fCblBbrFTEH92uXmbmOlxZLcoX4TotDq0e9YCHAglVZHB0nBlLFZk7bfaEWVhg1N7Egqe2LN6tHxlvB5nh54c9l9Z-e1sQtyl5ZtW3bTxBlvN8JiGZRCyuYAqygDU0W5OAAAVImib9DAwd02A6DBCLgAAKDAJyTDtfzgAANbMMlzABNQsgXKJjKNwgwaKgmjTVYoE4HKLCxhgLiWNLQTEOQySy0rLIAEpUOkegrSwGBNAgB0uGAGAMKgWxYFkMC2wAeUQXlOzgbsAMKWwTQo7cqM8Uc2HHJzeW6LRdBHIZ8LdUiuCKcUhjAAy8CM2ZlCGCsWzbH08BMiDDHUPy4O8BTZgrCBNAsEUj1qUiwsMuQj20ooADovQU-LSCC2wqsOIJioiuR4hoWLwPhEQEEhHSCrI+q8AqmCasJOrdP0krjLi4BzN5QLKpg0LwqyOQYtmhTut6-rxpkIkDJpctgCOgBRKADKgUiAAMptaw9bXgC56HSYA8q0ykimura2DEMQOU1OBVMQdTNIdP5JtWoykrIAzUEs4xOL7NhHNs5yUt8NykdsLzen6VLMEx7xFtsEK4AiGAiSizLOiS-G0pPfwOitZ7XrywloXgLgIGQKAsGAWYRJwop+nw2cWeAF6BDymghuAcRSBpIlNGhQaeb54AxskzRCopokyspdX+ca5otcE4EonCCpJJ60ldtkw3ef5k5uad4ARuw8Ybd+hWBtIgBCV2NbN94ohgXnXVIf7SDDiPHY1k3wmapoiViUQgA) TypeScript playground now. Here is the code:

```
export enum Scope {
  Form = "form",
  Nest = "nest",
}

export type ScopeKeyListType<
  L extends Scope,
  T extends ScopeType<L>,
> = T['parent'] extends ScopeType<infer A extends Scope>
  ? keyof T['data'] | ScopeKeyListType<A, T['parent']>
  : keyof T['data']

export type ScopeNestDataType = {
  index: number;
  nest: {
    foo: string;
    bar: boolean;
  };
};

export type ScopeFormDataType = {
  hello: string;
  world: number;
};

export type ScopeTableType = {
  form: ScopeFormDataType;
  nest: ScopeNestDataType;
};

export type ScopeType<
  A extends Scope,
  B extends unknown = unknown
> = {
  data: ScopeTableType[A];
  like: A;
  parent?: B extends ScopeType<infer T extends Scope, infer Q>
    ? B
    : never
};

export type ScopeValueType<
  L extends Scope,
  T extends ScopeType<L>,
  K extends string | number | symbol,
> = T['data'] extends { [key in K]: unknown }
  ? T['data'][K]
  : T['parent'] extends ScopeType<infer A extends Scope>
  ? ScopeValueType<A, T['parent'], K>
  : never

export type ParentScopeType<S> =
  | S
  | (S extends ScopeType<infer X, infer Y>
      ? Y extends ScopeType<infer A, infer B>
        ? ParentScopeType<Y>
        : never
      : never)

export function setPropertyValueOnScope<
  L extends Scope,
  S extends ScopeType<L>,
  K extends ScopeKeyListType<L, S>
>(scope: S, property: K, value: ScopeValueType<L, S, K>): void {
  if (property in scope.data) {
    scope.data[property] = value;
  } else if (scope.parent) {
    setPropertyValueOnScope(scope.parent, property, value);
  } else {
    throw new Error(`Property not defined on scope`);
  }
}

export function getPropertyValueFromScope<
  L extends Scope,
  S extends ScopeType<L>,
  K extends ScopeKeyListType<L, S>,
>(scope: S, path: K): ScopeValueType<L, S, K> | undefined {
  let source: ParentScopeType<S> | undefined = scope

  while (source) {
    if (path in source.data) {
      break
    } else {
      source = source.parent
    }
  }

  if (!source) {
    return
  }

  return source.data[path]
}
```

How do I resolve this conundrum? The first error occurs in the function `setPropertyValueOnScope` at this line:

```
scope.data[property] = value;
```

Error is:

```
Type 'K' cannot be used to index type 'ScopeTableType[L]'.(2536)
```

I checked that the keys can be passed to props in a more primitive example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBA0lMBnAPAFQHwwLwwNaID2AZjGsMMQK4B2AxiAJaE0xJQgAKAToRCsBhkYUAB4goNACZIYhAEYArKAwA0g+CPGSZ8RKkzAMACgWKAXGVUwIvCJbjWAbgEMANlSiW0AbTgBdAEpLJ0JGKRgAbw0zH1s+fxwYVw8oYABfCnBoGAAxQkJ0LQlpWSQQbkYaAHMYAB8YGioAW3kobnq2MFbCNyxcckpaBmZWdi47ACYBITRinVkzFRB1ITh50ryClARkdAwMI1Mlb2t4+3hnd09vPyCQsIjooVjzxNwUzwysyFgAVXY3DQvySzxEzRcjDclnKlRq32AdBY5RgVEBlgB7WBOVwYKgEKhlgA5MQCgABeQubgAOiRzSJCPGPD4KExQN+1iJ+MhbiJJjR7U53KhRKFohczQgbigtMI9MCQA), so it seems like this bigger example should work, but for some reason it's not. Can you spot why it's not working and how to fix it?

Comment: This doesn't seem different enough from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74880109/2887218) for them both to be open.  Could you close/delete one of them, or [edit] one of them to make it very clear what the differences are?

Comment: This also, unfortunately, doesn't seem to be a [mre] and I'm not sure how to engage further.  When you write `T extends ScopeType<L>`, you are not using the second argument to `ScopeType`, so it will just be `unknown`, in which case `ScopeType<L>` is identical to `{data: ScopeTableType[L]; like: S; parent?: undefined}`.  Unless you intend this to have no `parent`, then it's not even going to work how you want from the caller's side.  Until and unless your function call signature behaves how you want, it's not really worth trying to work on type checking the implementation.